# Why do people call the jQuery $ alias a 'factory'?

Tags: jquery

On various sites, jQuery's `$` variable is referred to as an alias, and on others, it is referred to as a factory.  I took a look at the source code, and I think the former is correct.  As far as I can see, the dollar symbol is being defined here:

```
// Expose jQuery to the global object
return (window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery);
```

This is setting both `$` and `jQuery` to the SAME alias; there is no 'factory' for jQuery objects.  Are the sites referring to `$` as a 'factory' simply wrong?

Comment: So we should refer to `$` as factory alias

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think either is an okay term. The dollar sign is certainly an alias for the `jQuery` function, specifically to be used as a shorthand. If someone refers to the function as a factory, I don't think that's specific to the `$` alias, but just describing what the `jQuery` function does in general, which is create objects from various different types of input.

Answer (score 3):

The `jQuery` function (on the right of the assignment in your question) is a factory (it creates new jQuery objects).  It is not in the global scope, because it is defined in the scope of a self-executing function.

`window.$` and `window.jQuery` are global aliases for the constructor.